# Creating the % functionality in calculator

Tags: objective-c, ios, calculator

I am doing a simple calculator in xcode. I have done the basic functions such as +,/, -,1/x, √. Now i am trying to do the % functionality. Not sure how to start on this.. Need some guidance on this...

Edited:

```
5/8% = 62.5
5x8%=0.4
5+8% = 5.4
5-8% = 4.6
```

It should be able to handle different functions before it.. That's why i am confused...

Comment: Do you mean percent or modulus?

Comment: Uh, percent is calculated by multiplying by 100.0.

Comment: i know that... i edited my qn to show the different types...

Comment: your 'examples dont make sense.. and anyways: as @HotLicks said, its * 100

Comment: That's not how the percentage operator works. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the [**modulo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator:

For integers simply use

```
int result = a % b;
```

For floats use [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/) (math.h)

```
float result = fmod(a, b);
```

If you mean the **percent** operator you have to remember that taking X percent of something is the same as multiplying it with `X/100`:

```
float result = a * X / 100.f;  // result will be X percent of a.
```

**EDIT** (to answer your edited question):

That's not how a percentage operator works on any calculator I know. The percentage sign is just a division by 100. So in your example:

```
5/8% = 5/8/100 = 0.00625
5x8% = 5x8/100 = 0.4
5+8% = 5+8/100 = 5.08
5-8% = 5-8/100 = 4.92
```

I think what you mean by `5+8%` is actually `5+5x8%` or `5+5x8/100`.

Comment: On my calculator 5/8/100 = 0.00625.  You mean 5/8*100.